# How Can I Add Premiss-Rule Labels to Proofs?

Tags: tabularx, enumitem

My thesis contains some logic proofs, but I want them formatted in a particular way, with the premisses and rules employed aligned on the right.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[label = (\arabic*)]
    \item $(p_{1} \wedge p_{2} \wedge p_{3} \wedge p_{4} \wedge p_{5} \wedge p_{6} \wedge p_{7} \wedge p_{8} \wedge p_{9} \wedge p_{10}) \supset (q_{1} \wedge q_{2} \wedge q_{3} \wedge q_{4} \wedge q_{5} \wedge q_{6} \wedge q_{7} \wedge q_{8} \wedge q_{9} \wedge q_{10}) $

    \item $p_{1} \wedge p_{2} \wedge p_{4} \wedge p_{3} \wedge p_{5}$

    \item $p_{6} \wedge p_{7} \wedge p_{8} \wedge p_{9} \wedge p_{10}$

    \item $p_{1} \wedge p_{2} \wedge p_{3} \wedge p_{4} \wedge p_{5} \wedge p_{6} \wedge p_{7} \wedge p_{8} \wedge p_{9} \wedge p_{10}$

    \item $q_{1} \wedge q_{2} \wedge q_{3} \wedge q_{4} \wedge q_{5} \wedge q_{6} \wedge q_{7} \wedge q_{8} \wedge q_{9} \wedge q_{10}$

\end{enumerate}
```

This outputs:

[image]

But I would like to include the premiss numbers and rules employed aligned on the right, like this:

[image]

I've tried a couple of different ways, but nothing is giving me the results I want. For example:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}
\begin{flalign*}
(1) & (p_{1} \wedge p_{2} \wedge p_{3} \wedge p_{4} \wedge p_{5} \wedge p_{6} \wedge p_{7} \wedge p_{8} \wedge p_{9} \wedge p_{10}) \supset (q_{1} \wedge q_{2} \wedge q_{3} \wedge q_{4} \wedge q_{5} \wedge q_{6} \wedge q_{7}) & (RA) & \\
(2) & p_{1} \wedge p_{2} \wedge p_{3} \wedge p_{4} \wedge p_{5} & (RA) & \\
(3) & p_{6} \wedge p_{7} \wedge p_{8} \wedge p_{9} \wedge p_{10} & (RA) & \\
(4) & p_{1} \wedge p_{2} \wedge p_{3} \wedge p_{4} \wedge p_{5} \wedge p_{6} \wedge p_{7} \wedge p_{8} \wedge p_{9} \wedge p_{10} & (2,3 \wedge I) & \\
(5) & q_{1} \wedge q_{2} \wedge q_{3} \wedge q_{4} \wedge q_{5} \wedge q_{6} \wedge q_{7} & (1,4 MP) & \\
\end{flalign*}

\end{document}
```

Gives me:

[image]

But this pushes the labels on the right off the page when the premisses are too long. And another attempt using tabularx (which I don't really know how to use):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}X@{}X@{}X@{}}
        (1) & $(p_{1} \wedge p_{2} \wedge p_{3} \wedge p_{4} \wedge p_{5} \wedge p_{6} \wedge p_{7} \wedge p_{8} \wedge p_{9} \wedge p_{10}) \supset (q_{1} \wedge q_{2} \wedge q_{3} \wedge q_{4} \wedge q_{5} \wedge q_{6} \wedge q_{7} \wedge q_{8}) $ & (RA) \\
        (2) & $p_{1} \wedge p_{2} \wedge p_{3} \wedge p_{4} \wedge p_{5}$ & (RA) \\
        (3) & $p_{6} \wedge p_{7} \wedge p_{8} \wedge p_{9} \wedge p_{10}$ & (RA) \\
        (4) & $p_{1} \wedge p_{2} \wedge p_{3} \wedge p_{4} \wedge p_{5} \wedge p_{6} \wedge p_{7} \wedge p_{8} \wedge p_{9} \wedge p_{10}$ & (2,3 $ \wedge $I) \\
        (5) & $q_{1} \wedge q_{2} \wedge q_{3} \wedge q_{4} \wedge q_{5} \wedge q_{6} \wedge q_{7} \wedge q_{8}$ & (1,4 MP)
    \end{tabularx}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Which gives:

[image]

Ideally, what I'd like is for something that behaves like the enumitem environment but allows me to put the premiss-rule labels on the right (level with the top line when the premiss spans over two lines).

Thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use `enumerate` rather than alignments.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,enumitem}

\newenvironment{deduction}
 {\enumerate[label=(\arabic*),ref=\arabic*]}
 {\endenumerate}

\newcommand{\filler}[1]{%
  \unskip\nobreak\hfill\penalty50\hskip1em\null\nobreak
     \hfill\mbox{(#1)}{\parfillskip=0pt \par}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{deduction}
\item\label{a}
     $(p_{1} \wedge p_{2} \wedge p_{3} \wedge p_{4} \wedge p_{5} \wedge p_{6} \wedge 
       p_{7} \wedge p_{8} \wedge p_{9} \wedge p_{10}) \supset\hfill\break (q_{1} \wedge q_{2} \wedge 
       q_{3} \wedge q_{4} \wedge q_{5} \wedge q_{6} \wedge q_{7} \wedge q_{8} \wedge 
       q_{9} \wedge q_{10})$\filler{RA}

\item\label{b}
     $p_{1} \wedge p_{2} \wedge p_{4} \wedge p_{3} \wedge p_{5}$\filler{RA}

\item\label{c}
     $p_{6} \wedge p_{7} \wedge p_{8} \wedge p_{9} \wedge p_{10}$\filler{RA}

\item\label{d}
      $p_{1} \wedge p_{2} \wedge p_{3} \wedge p_{4} \wedge p_{5} \wedge p_{6} \wedge
       p_{7} \wedge p_{8} \wedge p_{9} \wedge p_{10}$\filler{\ref{b}, \ref{c}, $\wedge$I}

\item\label{e}
     $q_{1} \wedge q_{2} \wedge q_{3} \wedge q_{4} \wedge q_{5} \wedge q_{6} \wedge 
      q_{7} \wedge q_{8} \wedge q_{9} \wedge q_{10}$\filler{\ref{a}, \ref{b}, MP}
\end{deduction}

\end{document}
```

Look for “Bourbaki” on the site for the definition of `\filler`.

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much, this worked a treat!

Answer (score 0):

This can be done within `amsmath`.

- Added the `leqno` option to move equation numbers to the left of the expressions and `fleqn` to reduce spacing from the left margin.
- Added a `\label{}` for each row so that you can `\ref{}` them easily in the "deduction column" - They will also change when the order of premises changes, and you can `\ref{}` them outside of a proof.
- Used the `alignat` environment with option `{2}` to explicitly specify the spacing between columns, with `\quad` in the first row.
- The first column is a "dummy" column to ensure alignment.
- Used `\text{}` as recommended by the `amsmath` manual. Actually if "MP" is an abbreviation for "modus ponens", then you woulnd't want to use `$MP$` because that means "the product M*P", as indicated by the different kerning of `$MP$` vs. `$\text{MP}$`.
- For the first, long line, included a nested `aligned` to break at a decent point.

---

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[leqno,fleqn]{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{alignat}{2}
\label{eq:1} & \begin{aligned}(p_{1} \wedge p_{2} \wedge p_{3} \wedge p_{4} \wedge p_{5} \wedge p_{6} \wedge p_{7} \wedge p_{8} \wedge p_{9} \wedge p_{10}) \supset\\ (q_{1} \wedge q_{2} \wedge q_{3} \wedge q_{4} \wedge q_{5} \wedge q_{6} \wedge q_{7} \wedge q_{8} \wedge q_{9} \wedge q_{10}) \end{aligned} &\quad& \text{(RA)} \\
\label{eq:2} & p_{1} \wedge p_{2} \wedge p_{4} \wedge p_{3} \wedge p_{5} && \text{(RA)}  \\
\label{eq:3}& p_{1} \wedge p_{2} \wedge p_{4} \wedge p_{3} \wedge p_{5} && \text{(RA)} \\
\label{eq:4}& p_{6} \wedge p_{7} \wedge p_{8} \wedge p_{9} \wedge p_{10} &&  \text{(\ref{eq:2}, \ref{eq:3} $\wedge$  I)}\\
\label{eq:5}& p_{1} \wedge p_{2} \wedge p_{3} \wedge p_{4} \wedge p_{5} \wedge p_{6} \wedge p_{7} \wedge p_{8} \wedge p_{9} \wedge p_{10} && (\ref{eq:1}, \ref{eq:4}, \text{MP})
\end{alignat}
\end{document}
```